# Calculate the number of nonnegative integer solutions of $ax+by\leq c$.

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions, combinatorial-geometry, integer-lattices

> If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are known, and $x$ and $y$ are integers greater than or equal to zero, 
>   how many possible values of ($x$, $y$) exist that satisfy the equation
>   $$ax + by \le c\,?$$

I have worked it out to equal the following:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor c/a \rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{c - an}{b}\right\rfloor\right)+\left\lfloor\frac{c}{a}\right\rfloor+1$$

I am trying to solve this as a coding problem, and at the moment this requires a loop:

```
int sum = 0;
int nMax = c/a;
for(int n = 0; n <= nMax; ++n)
    sum += (c-a*n)/b;
sum += nMax + 1;
```

It would be faster if I could figure out how to take away this loop.

I attempted another simplification step, with the following (incorrect) formula:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor c/a \rfloor}(c-an)}{b}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{c}{a}\right\rfloor + 1$$

My understanding is that this is incorrect because the floor function is not linear:

$$\sum_{n=0}^c\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor \ne \left\lfloor \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{c}n}{m}\right\rfloor$$

I'm stuck now. Is there another way to solve the problem, which doesn't involve such a large loop?

---

It occurs to be that you could express this as a line:

$$ax + by \le c$$
$$y \le \frac{c}{b} - \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)x$$

So the problem can now be expressed as:

> How many lattice points are on or below the line
>   $$y = \frac{c}{b} - \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)x$$

Comment: Interesting. The original inequality is symmetric (it has the same number of solutions if $a$ and $b$ are swapped), but your formula looks asymmetric. I can see it's correct, though.

Comment: Maybe Pick's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) could help you

Comment: If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers such that $a$ and $b$ are divisors of $c$, then it can be seen that the number of points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $ax+by\leq c$ is $$1+\frac{c}{2a}+\frac{c}{2b}+\frac{c}{2\,\text{lcm}(a,b)}+\frac{c^2}{2ab}\,.$$  Otherwise, it seems hopeless to simplify the sum.

Comment: @TitoEliatron It appears that Pick's Theorem requires the vertices to be on lattice points. In this case the vertices will be on (0, 0), (0, c/b), (c/a, 0), so I don't think I can apply it.

Comment: White if you take a segment with integer endpoints but near enough? I am thinking on integer part of b/a and integer part of c/a.

Comment: @TitoEliatron - Sadly, I can't do that. I am exploring ways to solve a Project Euler puzzle, and it doesn't give me the luxury of being off by even one.